# reading .csv.zst file with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, zstandard

I want to load `.csv.zst` into a dataframe:

```
for ex in examples:
    path = root + "f=" + ex + "/" + date
    data = os.listdir(path)
    
    for d in data:
        zst_datapath = path + "/" + d
        with open(zst_datapath, 'rb') as fh:
            data = fh.read()
            dctx = zstd.ZstdDecompressor(max_window_size=2147483648)
            decompressed = dctx.decompress(data)
```

What I want do is read the decompressed file as csv file:

```
with open(decompressed, 'rb') as f:
    csv_data = f.read()
    csv = pd.read_csv(csv_data)
```

However, I get a `File name too long` error. How do I load the decompressed data into pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that after going:

```py
decompressed = dctx.decompress(data)
```

The variable `decompress` now contains the whole un-compressed data (so the content itself of the csv.zst.
And then when you do:

```py
with open(decompressed, 'rb') as f:
```

You are trying to open a file whose ***name*** is "{content of your csv}".

What you are thinking about is making an input stream of the decompressed data. Module [io's StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) is what you would be looking for. You pass it a text content, you get a file-like object that works as if it was coming from a file opened with `open()`:

```py
import io

with io.StringIO(decompressed) as f:
   csv_data = f.read()
   csv = pd.read_csv(csv_data)
   # crashes here:---^
```

Except that, THIS WILL crash too, because `read_csv()` is considering strings as being a "path", so again it will be looking a file whose ***name*** is "{content of your csv}".

If you want to pass a block of text to csv_read, you need to pass the f object itself:

```py
import io

with io.StringIO(decompressed) as f:
   csv = pd.read_csv(f)
```

This *will* work, EXCEPT THAT, [read _csv can also decompress files](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).
So with recent pandas you can actually completely skip the whole "decompression" part, and directly give the file name. Pandas will take care of decompressing:

```py
csv = pd.read_csv(zst_datapath)
```

note that different compression scheme requires different dependencies to be installed to work.

Hope that this helps.